# How to insert into both parent and relevant child table in Oracle db?

Tags: database, oracle

Let's say I have 3 tables called Person, Teacher, Student. Teacher and Student tables are Child tables of the Person table.

[image]

When I insert a new row into the Person table, it should automatically insert the relevant data (Salary/School) into the relevant table. Student Ids starts as STxxxx and Teacher Ids starts as Txxxx.
I tried to figure out several examples of triggers but I couldn't apply it for this scenario.
How can I achieve this using Oracle database? Or is there any other way to create this relationship in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INSERT` trigger as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PERSON_TRG 
    AFTER INSERT ON PERSON
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    IF :NEW.ID LIKE 'ST%' THEN
        INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES ( :NEW.ID, <SCHOOL_NAME>);
    ELSIF :NEW.ID LIKE 'T%' THEN
        INSERT INTO TEACHER VALUES (:NEW.ID, <SALARY> );
    END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: How can I insert data?

Comment: As you already mentioned  **When I insert a new row into the Person table, it should automatically insert the relevant data (Salary/School) into the relevant table.**  You need to insert data in PERSON table and insertion in the relevant table will be done by the trigger